# Does a curated environment needs an internet outbound connection to download the packages

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I was able to run an experiment by allowing mcr.microsoft.com. We wants to use the curated environment AS-IS, no custom packages will be installed.

For the security reason I don't want to whitelist the [application firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-azureml-behind-firewall?tabs=ipaddress%2Cpublic#outbound-configuration) rules:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest versions of training curated environments referencing the images from MCR. Only AzureFrontDoor service tag is required for those.